# Is there any ways to concatenate 3 or more tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to concatenate 3 or more datasets in TensorFlow.
To concatenate 2 datasets,

```
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 8)
dataset1.concatenate(dataset2)
```

However, in this way,3 or more datasets cannot concatenate.
So I want to do like

```
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 8)
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.range(8, 12)
concatenate(dataset1,dataset2,dataset3)
```

Is there any ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific example you could just do

```
concat_dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2).concatenate(dataset3)
```

Note that you have to assign the result of `concatenate` to a new variable! It doesn't operate in-place.

Of course this doesn't scale well if you have many datasets, but this should work:

```
datasets = [dataset1, dataset2, dataset3]  # can be more than 3 of course

concat_dataset = datasets[0]
for dset in datasets[1:]:
    concat_dataset = concat_dataset.concatenate(dset)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)

dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 8)

dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.range(8, 12)

 
def func(*datasets):

    out = {}

    for dataset in datasets:

        for key in dataset:

            if key in out:

                _value = out[key]

                out[key] = tf.concat([_value, dataset[key]], axis=-1)

            else:

                out[key] = dataset[key]

    return out


tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset1, dataset2, dataset3)).map(func)
```